# FBX import 2.7 vs 2.8

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, .fbx

I've been trying to import an fbx from a friend who works in modo so I could do a flip fluids simulation, the mesh comes in fine in 2.79b but there's no sign of the textures. 
I can go into edit mode select the appropriate map and texture but when I exit edit mode no texture is visible in render view or in a final render. Am I missing a step here? 
[image: edit mode with uv window open and texture map and UV map selected]

In 2.8 the images again have to be selected along with appropriate UV map but it does show them in the eevee but doesnt render in cycles but does in eevee.

Any idea whats going on? am I missing a step in the process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures). This gets literally asked twice every day...

Comment: Can you add an image of your material setup?

Comment: @metaphor_set I don't think this is a dupe of that, Johnsta appears to be talking about setting the materials back up after the import, the fbx part is probably a  red herring

Comment: @Sazerac  - it's just the reverse process. .fbx material settings aren't necessarily compatible with Blender, so you have to set up a working material.

Comment: Heck! this is so  simple its untrue - Im not surprised it gets asked twice a day!

Comment: all I needed to do was be in texture mode click use nodes and input the texture via a image texture node into the diffuse. However although Ive done the same for each one, the render view shows two pieces with the texture the other two render black?

Comment: heres a bit of the file if it helps - Thanks [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6065" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6065/)